# check if author has published posts in custom post type, then send mail

Tags: functions, author, count

I have a site where people can submit drafts to a custom post type from the frontend.

Once a user submits the form, a new WP user is created.

If the user is logged in the submitted user e-mail adress is already attached to a WP user, the new post draft will be assigned to that author.

So now I want to setup a function that sends two different emails to the author this when admin changed post status from `draft` to `published`.

1. If user has published posts in the custom post type already
2. If user does not have any published posts in the custom post type but a draft

## Current function (not working)

```
/** Notification - Draft goes online */
    function authorNotification($post_id) {
        global $wpdb;
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        if( ( $_POST['post_status'] == 'publish' ) && ( $_POST['original_post_status'] != 'publish' ) ) {

            $author_info = get_userdata($post->post_author);
            $author_id = $author_info->ID;

            $published_by_author = new WP_Query(array(
               'post_type' => 'my-custom-post-type', 
               'post_status' => array('published','pending'), 
               'author' => $author_id, 
               'nopaging' => true
            );
            if( $published_by_author->found_posts > 0 ) { // user has published posts
               // wp_mail something like "another post of yours is online"
            } else { // user does not have published posts
              // wp_mail something like "welcome, your first post is online"

            }
        }
    }
    add_action('publish_my-custom-post-type', 'authorNotification');
```

## Problem

When I submit my frontend form, a new user is created and the form contents are saved as a post draft. Fine so far.

But when the draft is published – and the author does not have any published posts yet – the first email saying "another post of yours is online" is being sent.

When submitting the form while being logged in, the same email is being sent again.

## Realizations on second thought...

Of course the post count will return `1` even if the user is new because the `wp_mails` are sent when their first post goes from `draft` to `published`. Duh.

I'm going to edit my code and post it here later.

Comment: What is the exact problem, a hook is not being called OR mail function is not working?

Comment: edited my question and noticed I'm stupid. of course the post count is at least 1 for the new user because the draft is published and THEN the mail is sent. duh.

Comment: Please post a proper answer, with your corrected code.